# Android yearly calendar like IOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, calendar, android-calendar

i want to create **yearly calendar in Android** like **`ios`** .

such as this photo .
with year , month and date .

i do it with 2 listviews and 1 gridview but , i have lag between year items .

for 50 years .with 12 month with text .

---

[image]

Comment: Just do it. What the problem?

Comment: i have lag between year item . i have heavy process .

Comment: https://github.com/square/android-times-square

Comment: @Er.Arjunsaini , i want 3 columns of month , your link dosen't suitable .

Comment: @adnan9011 try my answer it''s well work for 2 column check for three with playing this code..: ) happy coding

Comment: You will able to show 3 column by this using yearview.xml layout change.. See codee and answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example..

https://github.com/ik024/CalendarLibrary

For YearView (this show two columns please check this code how to set the two columns than you fulfill your requirement)

[image]

Add the following in your xml file:

```
 <com.github.ik024.calendar_lib.YearView 
    android:id="@+id/calendar_year_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Implement the YearViewClickListener in your Activity:

```
public class MonthViewDemo extends AppCompatActivity implements YearViewClickListeners{


@Override
public void dateClicked(int year, int month, int day) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "year: "+year+";\nmonth: "+month+";\nday: "+day, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //TODO: Perform your actions based on year or month or day clicked
  }


}
```

For more refer YearViewDemo.java file.

Customizations

Following attributes can be customized:

```
<attr name="currentDayTextColorYV" format="color"/>
<attr name="monthNameTextColorYV" format="color"/>
<attr name="daysOfMonthTextColorYV" format="color"/>
<attr name="daysOfWeekTextColorYV" format="color"/>
<attr name="eventDayBackgroundColorYV" format="color"/>
<attr name="eventDayTextColorYV" format="color"/>
<attr name="calendarBackgroundColorYV" format="color" />
<attr name="monthNameBackgroundColorYV" format="color" />
<attr name="displayYearTextColorYV" format="color" />
<attr name="headerBackgroundColorYV" format="color" />
<attr name="prevButtonBackgroundResourceYV" format="reference" />
<attr name="nextButtonBackgroundResourceYV" format="reference" />
```

For three columns you need to change

go to calendarlib/layout/yearView.xml

do this... and make all change according to you responsive or etc..

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <com.github.ik024.calendar_lib.custom.MonthView
                android:id="@+id/mv_year_view_jan"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.33" />

            <com.github.ik024.calendar_lib.custom.MonthView
                android:id="@+id/mv_year_view_feb"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.33" />

            <com.github.ik024.calendar_lib.custom.MonthView
                android:id="@+id/mv_year_view_march"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.33" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

or all other in three

Comment: i checked this github before , but . this example just have one year each screen . just 12 month each visible view . not scrolling , not yearly like IOS

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Calendar.md

these libraries might help you in achieving what you want.You can try altering some of these libraries according to your need.

Comment: you want this full output in one screen ?

Comment: yeah , 3 column of month , ech year has 3*4 month and so on .

Answer (score 0):

For a more "2023" approach, try https://github.com/m-i-n-a-r/tasticalendar, a library to easily implement a monthly or yearly calendar, also customizing it and highlighting a set of events. It supports Monet / Material You too.